# Failed to start EJB3 on JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I have been trying to get these beans to deploy properly to `JBoss AS 7` and continually getting errors.  The last problem was the actual data source was not being bound and thanks to some help from some of you I was able to make the right changes and get it bind.  However, the beans are still not starting.  The log shows that it tries to start every bean but then gives this error:

```
 09:31:51,832 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "dodsr.ear" was rolled back with no failure message
```

Which tells me nothing.  I've looked up the error and have found no answer.

I see this as it tries to start it:

```
 09:31:48,792 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "dodsr.ear"
```

and this:

```
 09:31:48,909 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "dodsr.jar"
```

But, immediately following the last one I see this:

```
09:31:48,910 INFO  [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions).

09:31:48,908 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-15) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."ejb3-container-jboss-beans.xml".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."ejb3-container-jboss-beans.xml".PARSE: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "ejb3-container-jboss-beans.xml"
```

Does this error have anything to do with my problem?

This is only one example of the problems I've found:

```
 09:31:49,196 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-12) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for DoDSRMGR
 09:31:49,214 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-9) Failed to define class org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory in Module "deployment.jboss-local-jdbc.rar:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/local/LocalManagedConnectionFactory (Module "deployment.jboss-local-jdbc.rar:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:396)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:243)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:73)
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:517)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:182)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at org.jboss.jca.validator.ValidateClass.<init>(ValidateClass.java:88) [ironjacamar-validator-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1582) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1034) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService$AS7RaDeployer.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:173)
at org.jboss.as.connector.metadata.deployment.ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.start(ResourceAdapterDeploymentService.java:100)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/resource/adapter/jdbc/BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:327)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:391)
    ... 20 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

Comment: Check `ejb3-container-jboss-beans.xml` for XML errors

Comment: @NikhilTalreja thanks.  What is supposed to be in this file?  It is only a few lines long.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">

 <annotation>@org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.annotations.DisableAOP</annotation>


   <!-- The provider for EJB3 UserTransactions -->
   <bean name="EJB3UserTransactionprovider" class="org.jboss.ejb3.tx.EJB3UserTransactionProvider">
      <constructor factoryClass="org.jboss.ejb3.tx.EJB3UserTransactionProvider" factoryMethod="getSingleton"/>
      <depends>UserTransactionRegistry</depends>
   </bean>
</deployment>

Comment: Can you paste a full stack trace? The ERROR you posted must have a cause. May be a configuration issue.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja - the log file is quite large plus I am not able to post it here, at least not entirely.  Can you be a little more specific please?  Should I post just places where I find an error in the log?

Comment: Try posting the exception trace.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja I found this line in the log file: [org.jboss.as.pojo] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017000: Found legacy bean/pojo namespace: urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0 - might be missing some xml features (potential exceptions). This type of line, refering to POJO appears many times with the potential exception message. I found one reference that suggested that this line (<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>) be removed from standalone.xml. Could this be a solution?

Comment: You can try. Although without a stack trace its not easy to figure out what is the exact problem here.

Comment: @NikhilTalreja when you say stack trace are you referring to the log file or something else?

Comment: Posting as an answer, since its too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stack trace you posted, it seems this dependency is missing:

```
jboss-common-jdbc-wrapper.jar
```

Can you check if there a version of this jar on your classpath?

Comment: I've modified the question to show one place where there seems to be a problem, there are 93 places where the word ERROR is in the log file.

Comment: is this supposed to be in the class path my bean jar or something else?

Comment: it needs to be inside the .ear or .war file you are deploying on the server.

Comment: So, for the deployment of the bean application (I'm using JDeveloper) I just add this file to the library/class path and redeploy?

Comment: Yes, please try that.

Comment: Strange how, even after including that jar file, the resulting jar file size didn't change at all...

Comment: No it did not.  Does the file naming-jboss-beans.xml have anything to do with my errors?  Is this file supposed to have my bean names in it or something?

Comment: do you have any more suggestions?